# How to test a custom implementation of an AVL tree

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, data-structures, stress-testing

I've implemented an [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) in C++ and would like to stress test it. To do that I need some other implementation of a AVL tree to compare the results.

As an acceptance criterion, I'm going to use preorder and postorder traversals. If they are matching appropriately with my results, it will mean that the algorithms are working correctly.

But the problem is that I couldn't found any C++ library containing an implementation of an AVL tree that provides a preorder and postorder traversal functionality. How else is it possible to stress test it?

Comment: There is source code e.g. on Rosetta Code: [AVL tree C++](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/AVL_tree#C.2B.2B). To add pre-order and post-order traversal shouldn't be that complicated, should it?

Comment: Scheff, thank you will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AVL tree maintains certain invariants. You just need to check it after every insertion or deletion, and don't waste your time trying to incorporate another implementation of an AVL tree into your project.

Comment: Do you mean the balance factor?

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան yes, exactly.